# Erro escapeshellarg()

Tags: php

Quando eu tento fazer um upload, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Estou usando o `framework CodeIgniter`.

Como eu poderia resolver este erro? No localhost funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Removi a tag `codeigniter` por não se tratar do problema do framework, ok?

Comment: Ok sim! Muito obrigado @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é uma função utilizada para trabalhar com linha de comando. Sendo assim, provavelmente, o servidor de hospedagem que você está usando está a bloqueando por questões de segurança.

Você terá que solicitar ao suporte a liberação dessa função no php.ini ou migrar o seu plano para ter o privilégio de poder usar essa função.

No local funciona normalmente, porque não há restrições quanto ao uso de `escapeshellarg` no seu `php.ini`.

Outra coisa que pode ser feita (dependendo do seu plano de hospedagem) é remover essa função da lista de funções presentes na linha onde se encontra `disabled_functions` no `php.ini`.

Parece que ainda há uma outra possibilidade: Se o php estiver rodando em `safe mode`, essas funções que trabalhando com processos e linha de comando são desabilitadas.

Comment: Ok, já havia solicitado ao servidor que fizessem o desbloqueio dessa função. Vou aguardar para retestar. Agradeço muito.